# Flex 4.5 Application backgroundColor won't go black

Tags: css, apache-flex, mobile

Did a lot of testing and searching and I can't seem to find the answer...

I have a Flex 4.5 mobile app, I'm trying to set the backgroundColor to black, aka 0x000000 at runtime.

It won't go black, in fact, it will go any other color but black.

Code:

```
application.setStyle( "backgroundColor", 0x000000 /* Any color, like 0x0000ff works, just not 0x000000 */ );
```

Anyone ever run into this???

Just as some extra info, I have my original Application backgroundColor #333333 set in a .css file and in the MXML Application node.

Comment: This is just a shot in the dark (no pun intended) but might it be that the backgroundAlpha is not 1 (100%)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To this date I cannot replicate this issue in another project, my guess is that something unknown was corrupted.